# Windows Media Player 11 cannot play media files properly

Tags: windows-vista, windows-media-player

When I try to double click on any media file (ie. mp3, wma) in Windows Vista Home Premium, Windows Media Player 11 doesn't start to play the file although these file types are associated with WMP.

When I try to right click on the media file and choose the 'open with' option, then choose Windows Media Player, an error message appears says:

> The parameter is incorrect

I have to start WMP manually, then play the files with it! So what's the problem?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior in the [Default Programs](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/defprogramvista.htm)?

Comment: No, it's just in WMP.

Comment: You haven't looked into Default Programs, please look there as that wasn't an answer to my question. Default Programs is not an application, it are the settings in the Control Panel that determine in which application your files are opened...

Comment: Yes, I know that. I looked there, WMP is the default application for playing MP3 files!